WebRTC ice gathering FF VS Chrome/Edge different results
I'm using https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ with google stun server for testing ice gathering on Firefox and Chrome browsers. When I connect to the additional work-related VPN which does not have internet access I'm starting to see differences in behavior between Chrome and FF.
For firefox:
I see host candidates and srflx candidates for interfaces with internet access.
Gathering is completed in milliseconds.
For Chrome:
Initial results are the same but gathering is not done. After 30-40 seconds I get additional error message from "onicecandidateerror" handler: 701: STUN binding request timed out. for the IP address (Ipv4) of the VPN interface.
Why is it behavior so different? I prefer FF behavior but what is the reason for this difference? Is there a way to configure Chrome to behave like FF?

